# Get selected option in ngOptions with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

How can I get the object associated to the selected option inside within a dropdown (`select`)?

Here's my html:

```
<select ng-model="selSeason" ng-options="season as season.name for season in seasons"></select>
```

Every season is an object with several properties and I'd need to get the object associated to the selected object (and not only its text or value).

I know `ng-repeat` has something like (to select name of the 5th season):

```
element(by.repeater('season in seasons').row(4).column('name'));
```

Is there something similar for `by.options()` selector?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`by.options`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.options) with [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
var seasonNames = element.all(by.options('season in seasons')).evaluate("season.name");
seasonNames.then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);  // array of season names is printed
});
```

You can also filter out the selected option with [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var selectedSeasonName = element.all(by.options('season in seasons')).filter(function (option) {
    return option.getAttribute("selected").then(function (selected) {
        return selected;
    });
}).first().evaluate("season.name");

selectedSeasonName.then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);  // selected season name is printed
});
```

Comment: This is actually pretty good, but it doesn't show how to get the selected option. Do that and you've got my vote.

Comment: @MBielski thanks, I think the update should solve it.

Comment: Nailed it. I had forgotten about using filter.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the custom by.selectedOption locator.

```
element(by.selectedOption('model_name'))
```

For a better description, read this: https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/protractor-and-dropdowns-validation/

Comment: I'm but it seems that by.selectedOption is not a valid Protractor selector according to the latest [doc](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api)

Comment: No, it's a custom selector that is added in. Read the article.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up evaluating not the selected option but the ng-model associated to the select:

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selSeason" ng-options="season as season.name for season in seasons"></select>
```

JS

```
element(by.model('selSeason')).evaluate('selSeason').then(function(season){
     console.log(season.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding looks good, you can read all the properties easily by using your ng-model variable 'selSeason', see this example

```
<select ng-model="user"               
        ng-options="x as x.name for x in users track by x.id"
        class="form-control" 
        ng-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Choose User --</option>
</select> 

var id = $scope.user.id; 
var name = $scope.user.name; 
var role = $scope.user.role
```

For more detail [check this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1196/angularjs-dropdown-select-value-text-multiple-values-with-demo)

Comment: Your solution has nothing to do with Protractor.

Comment: Just test it and say the same again, it will return the entire object, I already tested it. :)